# How do I stop blinking of content in Recyclerview when data is added or changed in Firebase database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, event-listener

I creating a social app that stores and fetches posts and other data from firebase database. But each time a change is made like liking a post or deleting a post the app blinks (reloads data in recyclerview). Since I am fetching post data from a child node "Posts" in firebase, using addListenerForSingle event prevents the blinking but features like counting the number of likes or removing the post on delete don't function until I manually refresh the fragment for changes to show. Using addValueEventlistener updates everything in realtime but causes the blinking or flickering.
How do I stop the flickering/blinking but at the same time able to listen for changes such as liking or deleting post?
My code for loading post in fragment is as below

{
private void loadPosts() {

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
   
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            postList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelPost modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);

                postList.add(modelPost);

                postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
               
                recyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            //in case of errors
            //Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

And my PostAdapter.java class code is:

{
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.MyHolder>{

```
Context context;
List<ModelPost> postList;

String mUid;

DatabaseReference likesRef; //For likes database node
DatabaseReference postRef; //Posts reference

boolean mProcessLikes = false;

public PostsAdapter(Context context, List<ModelPost> postList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = postList;

    mUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflate layout row_post.xml
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_posts, parent, false);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

    String userUid = postList.get(position).getUserUID();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelUser user = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);

                //get data
                assert user != null;
                String myUid = user.getUid();

                if (myUid.equals(userUid)) {
                    String userProfilePic = user.getProfilepic();
                    String firstName = user.getFirstname();
                    String lastName = user.getLastname();
                    String userNickName = user.getNickname();

                    //set data
                    Glide
                            .with(context.getApplicationContext())
                            .load(userProfilePic)
                            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                            .into(holder.avatarTv);

                    holder.firstnameTv.setText(firstName);
                    holder.lastnameTv.setText(lastName);
                    holder.nicknameTv.setText(userNickName);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    String postTimeStamp = postList.get(position).getPostTime();
    String userPost = postList.get(position).getUserPost();
    String postLikes = postList.get(position).getPostLikes(); //contains total number of likes for a post

    //set data

    holder.postTv.setText(userPost);

    //delete message
    holder.moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
   

    holder.likesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    //increase and decrease likes count in button click
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

}

private void setLikes(MyHolder holder, String postKey) {
    likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //What like button does
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postList.size();
}

//view holder class
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //views from row_posts layout


    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //init views here
        
    }
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path: it is indeed most likely that the blinking is caused by the fact that you're refreshing all data in the adapter each time, even when only a small subset of that data has changed.

If that is indeed the cause, you can fix it by only telling the adapter to update the data that has actually change. You can [use `addChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) from Firebase, to get notified of which specific child nodes have changed. Then, for example, when a child node is added your `onChildAdded` is called, and you can then add the new node to the adapter's data source and [notify it that an item was inserted](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)). You'd do the same for each event from Firebase:

- `ChildEventListener.onChildAdded` -> `Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)`
- `ChildEventListener.onChildRemoved` -> `Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int)`
- `ChildEventListener.onChildChanged` -> `Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)`
- `ChildEventListener.onChildMoved` -> `Adapter#notifyItemMoved(int)`

The `ChildEventListener` methods get a snapshot, while the `RecyclerView.Adapter` method take a position as a parameter. So you'll need to write code to keep track of what snapshot from the database is in what position in the adapter, typically by either keeping a list of snapshots or a list of just their keys.

If you're looking for a source of inspiration for this, have a look at the [`FirebaseArray` class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) in the FirebaseUI library, which is used as the basis for that library's adapters and implements both a list to track snapshot positions, and a notification mechanism.

Comment: Since I already provided the code, could you at least show me what changes to make, how and where?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. I confirmed what causes the flicker, explained how to solve it, and pointed at a code sample that implements the solution.